# how to fill the timestamp by input something in the textfield manually?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, web

I am not a web developer. So my question maybe a bit silly.

The scenario is quite simple: there are two text fields for user to input username and email address and one button to click to send the inputs to the server.

Normally there is nothing special, but i check the datagram send to the server by using google chrome's developer tools, and i find there is actually three items: name,email,timestamp. And timestamp is an empty string. Then how can i fill these 3 items by only 2 textfields and also don't know the code?

The server side is a black box. I think what i can do is input somethings to these 2 textfields and click the button. I wonder can i just add something in the second text field to fill the email and the timestamp field together? Or any other techniques i can use?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

P.S.

1.This is just an interesting test. i want to try it out. If success, there should be something come out when click the button. But when i click there is nothing but a warning to let me try to see the datagram. when i check the datagram, i see there is one timestamp which is empty. i guess i should try to fill the timestamp to make it.

2.The request method is `POST`. Status Code:`200 OK`

```
Request Payload {name:XXX,email:XXXXXX,timestamp:}
   email:"XXXXXX"
   name:"XXX"
   timestamp:""
```

3. The form code is as follows:(i copy by viewing source of the page)

```
<form class="mt30" id="msgForm">
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name" />
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" />
<input type="hidden" name="timestamp" />
<div class="mt30"><button class="btn" id="btnSubmit">open</button></div>
</form>
```

Comment: @SilviuBurcea there is no code. server side is a blackbox. I want to fill all these three items then send to server.

Comment: Filling means a client side action so client side code. HTML/JS :) Also, you can detect if there is any Javascript when you start the POST request. Chrome's tools will help you very much.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea sorry, now i paste the form code here.

Comment: Select the timestamp element in the Chrome JS console and set a value. Additionally, you can inject a script that will do that for you before the form is submitted.

Comment: @SilviuBurcea how to inject in the console before submitted? can you write some details?

Answer (score 1):

The following returns the number of milliseconds since the epoch in Js

time_stamp = new Date().getTime();

Just Send It With The Post fileds.

If So And don't No If I Should answer This But :

Go To This Site [epochconverter](http://www.epochconverter.com/) And Copy The current Unix epoch time And Place It In The TextFiled

Comment: i cannot write code. what i can do is fill two textfields and click the button.

Comment: you mean i input like this "123@xxx.com time_stamp = new Date().getTime();" in the textfield?